# Linq get single column data count

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two relation tables.
1st table is the person detail table

```
PersonID    PersonName    Sex
1           Anand         Male
2           Prabhu        Male
3           Durga         Female
```

2nd table is place traveld by person

```
PlaceID    Place   PersonID
1          a       1
2          b       2
3          c       1
4          d       3
5          e       1
6          f       2
```

My expected output is

```
PersonName     PLaceCount
1              3
2              2
3              1
```

the `PlaceCount` will be the count of the place traveled by the user.
Model

```
public class value
{
    public string PersonName{get;set;}
    public int PLaceCount{get;set;}
}
```

my code

```
var data= from t1 in db.Person
          join t2 in db.PlaceTraveled on t1.PersonID equals t2.PersonID
          select new value { PersonName = t1.PersonName, PLaceCount= t2.Place};
```

but i cant get the count of the place traveled by the person.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You just merge two table in ur query where did u write code of count?

Comment: After the join do a `group` and that should give you what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such scenarios, instead of a regular join you need to use a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), which according to the  [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Correlates the elements of two sequences based on key equality and **groups the results**.

The difference from the regular join is that you get an item and a **set** of related items. Then you can apply different aggregates on the related set, including `Count()`:

```
var data= from t1 in db.Person
          join t2 in db.PlaceTraveled on t1.PersonID equals t2.PersonID into placeGroup
          select new value { PersonName = t1.PersonName, PLaceCount = placeGroup.Count() };
```

If the combination of the `PlaceId` and `PersonId` in the second table is unique, the above is enough. If not, then you can simply combine it with `Distinct` like this:

```
var data= from t1 in db.Person
          join t2 in db.PlaceTraveled on t1.PersonID equals t2.PersonID into placeGroup
          select new value
          { 
              PersonName = t1.PersonName,
              PLaceCount = placeGroup.Select(p => p.PlaceId).Distinct().Count()
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be look something like this:
https://paragy.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/sql-inner-join-and-group-by-with-linq-and-lambda-expression/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?